# latex-dvips-ps2pdf

Tags: pstricks, pst-barcode

I use pdflatex, Windows7, and TeXnicCenter. I am interested in using `\psbarcode` in combination with `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`. A possible solution is to use latex-dvips-ps2pdf. The question is how to activate latex-dvips-ps2pdf. I found a detailed explanation [on the TeXworks site](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools#latex_-%3E_dvips_-%3E_ps2pdf)

> *Windows*
>   Create a file `latex-dvips-ps2pdf.bat` containing 
>   `@latex -synctex=1 "%1.tex" && dvips "%1.dvi" && ps2pdf "%1.ps"`
>   If `-synctex=1` causes problems, simply remove it.

I do not know how and where to create this `.bat` file for `latex-dvips-ps2pdf.` Could you please clarify this to me, or give me other suggestions, screenshots, etc. on how to proceed?

Comment: The easiest way is to use `xelatex` then you do not need any additional package

Comment: TeXWorks isn'T TeXniCenter. The editor TeXniCenter offers a compilation "LaTeX-ps-pdf". If you want to use `auto-pst-pdf you need `shell-escape`. For more information see: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput

Answer (score 9):

If you use TeXnicCenter, there's no need to create a `.bat` file. IMHO there's a more fluid way of doing that.

<sup>I'm using the alpha version of TeXnicCenter. I suppose the following steps also work with `1.x` branch.</sup>

Let's create a new output profile. Go to `Build > Define Output Profiles`.

[image: Image 1]

There are some predefined output profiles. Let's create a new profile based on an existing one. Select `LaTeX → DVI → PDF` and click  the `Copy` button.

[image: Image 2]

Let's give a new name for our profile. I'll use `(new) LaTeX → DVI → PDF`. Click `OK`.

[image: Image 3]

Now it's time to configure our new profile. Make sure our profile is selected in the list. The first tab is `(La)TeX`. Since we copied from another LaTeX workflow, we don't need to modify anything here.

[image: Image 4]

Go to the `Preprocessor` tab. The list should be empty. Let's move on.

[image: Image 5]

Now we are in the `Postprocessor` tab. Select the `dvipdfm` item and click the `Delete` button. The list is now empty.

[image: Image 6]

Let's add the first postprocessor of our workflow. Click the `New` button.

[image: Image 7]

Name it `dvips`.

[image: Image 8]

With `dvips` selected, now go to the `Executable:` field and click the `...` button.

[image: Image 9]

Find the `dvips.exe` executable. Mine is inside the `bin\win32` directory from TeX Live. Click `Open`.

[image: Image 10]

Now, in the `Arguments:` textfield, type `"%bm.dvi"` (with the quotes).

[image: Image 11]

Time to add the second postprocessor. Let's do the very same steps we did before. Add a new postprocessor called `ps2pdf`:

[image: Image 12]

With `ps2pdf` selected, go to the `Executable:` field and click the `...` button. Find the `ps2pdf.exe` executable and click `Open`.

[image: Image 13]

In the `Arguments:` textfield, type `"%bm.ps"` (with the quotes). We are done. Click the `OK` button.

[image: Image 14]

Open your `.tex` file (my example is from the `pst-barcode` manual).

[image: Image 15]

Make sure to select the new profile we created:

[image: Image 16]

And then compile your `.tex` file:

[image: Image 17]

The output:

[image: Image 18]

And everything works as expected. `:)`

If you want to use `auto-pst-pdf`, a simple `pdflatex` workflow might be enough, but in this case, note that `auto-pst-pdf` requires `--shell-escape` enabled (as Marco pointed out). The correct workflow would be `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex`.

Or you could use `xelatex` as Herbert suggested. `:)`

Comment: Windows? What? -- Is Fedora down?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I... I... have Windows installed too! */cries* Oh the shame! `:)` Someone has to make `arara` works on Windows too. `:P`